# Android Location manager - wait location

Tags: android, location, locationmanager

I have a code in the onCreate()

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(  
LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 1, new LocationListener (){
             @Override
             public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
                               CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude()));
                               myMap.moveCamera(center);  
             }
});
```

This occurs when the changes the user's position, but I want it to happen once.
I want to wait until the new location is received to move to a new location map, and then not move the map to the user

Comment: Can't understand what you mean. You want to set camera once for user location?

Comment: Yes. I want one just move the camera without using a method locationManager.getLastKnownLocation();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class member

```
private LocationManager mLocationManager; 
MyLocationListener mLocationListener 

locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
MyLocationListener mLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 1, myLocationListener);

public MyLocationListener extends LocationListener
{
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
              CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude()));
              myMap.moveCamera(center); 
              mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener): 
             }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
         {

         }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
        {

        }

}
```